# Any way to get folder of batch script if it is run from a different location?

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I have put my batch script's folder in my PATH environment variable, so I can open up any command prompt and can run it from anywhere. The problem is I have links to other files as relative paths in the script, so I need to get the path of the actual script.

Typing `~dp0` only gives me the path of the location I am in in the command prompt when running the script, and the same for `%cd%`. I would like the location of the actual script. Is this possible?

Comment: Many old timers, and young people, have a folder called `Util` which is also on the path, and it contains all third party executables that the batch files use.

Comment: How do you run your script? `%~dp0` seems to work for me - even when on a different directory.

Comment: @foxidrive I'm trying to read a text file which is in a subdirectory, if it was running an exe it would probably work if it was in a folder on the path, but other files don't seem to.

Comment: @konsolebox I run my script by just typing "keygen" into cmd. keygen.bat is in a different folder (on the path). %~dp0 just gives my the directory cmd is in.

Comment: `@echo %~dp0&pause` <--- put that in your batch file folder, in `aaa.bat` and then open a cmd prompt and type `aaa`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

:: build a simple batch file in "%sourcedir%" which is NOT on the path

(
ECHO @ECHO OFF
ECHO SETLOCAL
ECHO ECHO %%~dp0
)>"%sourcedir%\q24777129s.bat"

:: Force "%sourcedir%" into the path

SET path=%path%;%sourcedir%

:: execute the batch built

q24777129s

GOTO :EOF
```

This little script should demonstrate that `%~dp0` indeed shows the script file's location. In my case, it showed `U:\sourcedir\` which is not on the (original) path.

If it doesn't work for you, then we'd need more information, explicitly specifying the procedure you are using - what you are typing, where the script is located and the exact names of the batches/executables involved.